# Изменилось ли значение input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `<input placeholder="Вопрос" onblur="myFunc(this)" onkeydown="myFunc2(this, event)"  type="text">`

по `blur` срабатывает `myFunc`, можно ли в `myFunc` отследить было ли измененно значение внутри `input`, если - нет, то сделать `return`.
Нашел вариант для дефолтного значения `if(e.defaultValue === e.value)
    return;`

Но тут берется значение для сравнения которое было при рендере, этого мало) Можно ли отследить вдруг пользователь ввел в пустой `input` -> `123` - я сохранил. И если повторно он поставит курсор в `input` -> сработает `myFunc` и нужно понять сделал ли он изменения в поле `input`

Comment: Переменную создай и там храни текст с которым будешь сравнивать

Comment: я бы сделал через кастомный `data` атрибут, в который бы писал "старое" значение

Comment: Спасибо, за идею с data атрибутом, сейчас буду пробовать)

Comment: Если пользуешься jQuery то лучше сделай обработку событий через `$('input').on('change', ...`

Comment: @RuslanMelnichenko звучит так, будто бы через `js` так сделать нельзя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю вам при событии focus у инпута включать setInterval и в его коллбэке проверять, было ли изменено значение инпута. А при событии blur вызывать clearInterval. По такому принципу, грубо говоря, работает цикл digest в Angular.
То есть в вашем случае это будет выглядеть прмерно так:

```
<input placeholder="Вопрос" onblur="myFunc(this)" onfocus="myFunc1(this)" onkeydown="myFunc2(this, event)"  type="text">
```

JavaScript:

```
// переменная для хранения interval id
var intervalId;
function myFunc1(element) {
  // изначальное значение инпута
  var initialValue = $(element).val();
  // setInterval() возвращает interval id
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    // текущее значение инпута
    var currentValue = $(element).val();
    if(currentValue !== initialValue) {
     console.log('value has been changed!');
    }
  }, 100);
}

// обрабатываем событие blur
function myFunc(element) {
   clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо большое, ваш вариант помог)